# Как устранить перекрытие контента фиксированным блоком?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Имеется следующий код:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  font-family: PT Serif, serif;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
a {
  font-family: Proxima, sans-serif;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 25% auto;
}
.sections-menu,
.main-content {
  font-size: 1em;
}
.sections-menu {
  color: snow;
  background-color: #3f59ae;
  grid-row: -1;
  display: flex;
}
.sections-menu ul {
  margin: 30px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.sections-menu ul li {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.sections-menu ul li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.sections-menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: snow;
  font-size: 1.5625em;
}
.main-content {
  background-color: snow;
  grid-column: -2;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.main-content h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  margin: 15px auto 30px;
}
.main-content h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.main-content #examples {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.main-content h3 {
  font-size: 1.5625em;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.main-content p {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 33% auto;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto);
  }
  .sections-menu {
    width: 100%;
    grid-row: 1;
    position: fixed;
  }
}
```

При разрешении экрана 768px меню перемещается вверх и становится фиксированным. Однако при попытке перейти по ссылке-якорю меню перекрывает часть контента. Пробовал :before перед соответствующими частями контента, также пробовал вставлять блок, совпадающий по высоте с меню, перед контентом, однако не помогло. Как решить данную проблему?

Код полностью: https://codepen.io/sasha_jarvi/pen/oJOXZO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашел самостоятельно: комбинация элемента `.blocker`, который будет отображаться в мобильной версии сайта и будет равен по высоте `.sections-menu` и следующего скрипта:

```
$(function() {
            $(".sections-menu a[href^='#']").click(function(e) {
                let target = $(this).attr("href");
                $("html, body").animate({
                    scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - $(".sections-menu").outerHeight(true)
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
```

Итоговый код здесь: https://codepen.io/sasha_jarvi/pen/oJOXZO